# jQuery Datatable filtering loads the default settings

Tags: jquery, filter, datatable

I have a table created from jquery datatable which displays like above:
[image]

like you see above, the current show entries status is 25 but it shows only 10 rows which is the default value.
this is what I have called:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]]
    });
});
```

which the default one in its javascript library file is:

```
"aLengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 100]
```

And I don't know where to edit it to load 25 rows at start up.

So any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `iDisplayLength` according to the [docs](http://datatables.net/usage/options)

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    iDisplayLength: 25
});
​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/sThGk/15/)**

Hope this helps